# Is it bad practice to have instruction parameters as a part of the PDA seed?

Tags: anchor, pda, account

Let us suppose I have made a design, where I would be able to derive the PDA just by knowing the **ID**. So I have made a PDA that uses the inputted instruction **ID** parameter as a part of the seed.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: Params)]
pub struct Context<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"someSeed".as_ref(), params.id.as_bytes()]
        bump,
        payer = operator,
        space = N
    )]
    pub account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
```

So I was wondering if this is something I would need to be wary of?

The plan is to have this instruction only be callable by operators and not by any users, which I have already made checks for.

Comment: imo it depends on the usecase generally it's used when a authority needs to create n no of PDA accounts but then. you do have to track the seeds as well inorder to derive the PDA again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to keep in mind is potential DOS opportunities from someone crafting transactions with different IDs to create accounts, and potentially take control of them, if that's part of your program's logic. Otherwise, it should be fine!

Comment: Basically, since it is so easy to derive my PDAs, adversaries can easily occupy those addresses by creating those accounts? Thus when I try to create a new PDA, the account would already exist and my instruction/transaction would fail?

Comment: Yeah exactly. So if it's OK for anyone to create accounts, then you're fine

Comment: Mhhmm I see, it is about time that I think of a different design. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jon, weird request but do you have any social media that I can follow?:)

Comment: I tend to stay away from social media, sorry!